# How do I fill a UL with array items using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Trying to use jQuery to place array values into a `ul` of radio buttons.

**HTML**

```
<div class="quizWindow">
<h1>The Bridge Of Death</h1>
    <div id="question"></div>
        <form>
         <ul id = "choices">

         </ul>
        </form>
    <div id = "quizMessage"></div>
    <div id = "result"></div>
    <div id = "nextButton"><span>Start Quiz</span></div>
<br>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "What, is your name?", choices: ["Sir Lancelot the brave", "Sir Galahad the brave", "Sir not appearing in this film"], correctAnswer: 1}, {question: "What, is your quest?", choices: ["To seek the holy grail", "To dream the impossible dream", "To get back on the horse"], correctAnswer: 1 }, {question: "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?", choices: ["16mph", "I don't know that!", "What do you mean; an african or a european swallow?"], correctAnswer: 3}];

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Start Quiz, show first set of questions
    $('#nextButton').click(function () {
        $('#question').text(allQuestions[0].question);
            for (var i = 0; i <= allQuestions.length; i++) {

            $.each(allQuestions, function(i, question) {
                var $ul = $('<ul/>'); //make a new ul for this question

                //iterate through each choice for this question
                $.each(question.choices, function (i, choices) {
                    //add the choice to the ul
                    $ul.append('<li><label><input type="radio" name="question' + i + '" value="' + choices + '"> ' + choices + '</label></li>');
                });

                //add the new ul to the form
                $('.choices').append($ul);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've got the question showing up in the HTML, but none of the choices below it. I think this is a problem of my HTML formatting in the jQuery but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You just want an ordinary `for` or `$.each()` loop. Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it. Also, show what you want the resulting HTML to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `$.each` to iterate through objects and arrays. Please note I've changed the `name` for each input to be `'question'+question number`. This is because you obviously can't have multiple questions that all have the same `name`.

```
//iterate through each question
$.each(allQuestions, function(i, question){
    var $ul = $('<ul/>'); //make a new ul for this question

    //iterate through each choice for this question
    $.each(question.choices, function(ii, choice){
        //add the choice to the ul
        $ul.append('<li><label><input type="radio" name="question'+i+'" value="'+choice+'"> '+choice+'</label></li>');
    });

    //add the new ul to the form
    $('.choices').append($ul)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to loop.  Try something like this.

```
var $ul = $('ul.yourUl');

for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    var $li = $("<li></li>"); //Do whatever is needed to make this li

    $ul.append($li);
}
```